# How to return multiple values from a python class to the calling class

Tags: python, class, return

The parameters returned by called python class are not accessible in calling class. The called class retrieves values from a file and return them to the calling class.

The called class (XPGWGetParms) creates a dictionary to be return to calling class.

```
Class Main():
    def __init__(self, root, *args, *kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.kwargs = {}

    def return_data(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        self.kwargs = {
                    'text': self.text,
                    'codes': self.codes,
                    'darwin': self.darwin,
                    'windows': self.windows,
                    'linux': self.linux,
                    'raster_warning_level': self.raster_warning_level,
                    'padx': self.padx,
                    'pady': self.pady,
                    'win_background': self.win_background,
                    'screen_width': self.screen_width,
                    'screen_height': self.screen_height,
                    'char_width': self.char_width,
                    'progbar_maximum': self.progbar_maximum,
                    'window_app_name': self.window_app_name,
                    'default_font': self.default_font,
                    'next_step': self.next_step
                    }

        return self.kwargs
```

The calling class

```
class Main(tk.Frame)
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)        
        self.kwargs = {}
        self.text = {}
        self.codes = {}

        # Get text strings and parms
        self.kwargs = XPGWGetParms.Main(self, root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text = self.kwargs['text']
        self.codes = self.kwargs['codes']
```

I was expecting self.text in the calling class to be populated by the value assigned to the key 'text', i.e self.text. Instead I get a nested kwargs value, according to the debugger i.e.

```
 self={Main}.!main
     kwargs=Main<XPGWGetParms.Main...
         kwargs={dict}<class'dict>...
             'text'={dict}<class'dict>...
                 'APPNAME'={str}'Application Name'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it's probably pretty simple, but I can't work it out.

Comment: No, the code as you have posted it will give a TypeError because `self.kwargs` is an instance of `XPGWGetParms.Main` and that class doesn't define `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 0):

So I was not getting anywhere with the **getitem** route, so I did some further research and this works for me

```
self.instance_of_XPGWGetParms = XPGWGetParms.Main(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
self.kwargs = self.instance_of_XPGWGetParms.return_data()
```

I don't really understand either, but I'm working on it.

Many thanks